# How to find the variance of $U= X-2Y+4Z$? & The Co-variance of $U=X-2Y+4Z$ and $V = 3X-Y-Z$

Tags: statistics, covariance, variance

**EDIT**

> If the random variables $X,Y, Z$ have the expected,
>
> $$\text{ means: }\mu_{x}=2 \qquad \qquad \mu_{y}=-3 \qquad \qquad \mu_{z} = 4$$
>
> $$ \text{variances: }\sigma_{x}^{2}=3 \qquad \qquad \sigma_{y}^{2}=2 \qquad \qquad \sigma^{2}_{z}=8$$
>
> $$\text{covariances: }\text{cov}(X,Y) =1 \quad \quad \text{cov}(X,Z) = -2 \quad \quad \text{Cov}(Y,Z) = 3$$
>
> find the variance of $U = X-2Y+4Z$.
>
> The co-variance of $U$ and $V = 3X-Y-Z$

One must use these formulas in order to solve this problem.
[image]

[image]

[image]

From what I have deduced from the formulas above in order to find the variance one must use this formula $v(U)= \text{var}(a_x+b_y+c_z) =a^2\cdot \text{var}(x) +b^2\cdot \text{var}(Y)+c^2 \cdot \text{var}(z) + 2ab \cdot cov(x,y) +2ac\cdot \text{cov}(x,z)+2abc \cdot \text{cov}(Y,Z)$

To find the co-variance one must use this formula

$\text{cov}(u,v) = \text{cov}(a_1+b_1+c_1,a_2+b_2+c_2)=(a_{1})(a_{2})\text{var}(x)+(b_{1})(b_{2})\text{var}(Y)+(c_{1})(c_{2})\text{var}(Z)+\left[ (a_{1})(b_{2})+(b_{1})(a_{2}) \right] \cdot \text{cov}(X,Y)+\left[ (a_{1})(c_{2})+(c_{1})(a_{2}) \right] \cdot \text{cov}(X,Z)+ \left[ (b_{1})(c_{2})+(c_{1})(b_{2}) \right] \cdot \text{cov}(Y,Z)$

Is the formula that I used above a **correct** interpretation of what is alluded by in the formulas above?

Lastly, I do not want to make duplicates so the questions I have asked above is different from what I asked before in the previous questions, mainly because am asking  about the interpretations of the formulas...... not just the answer.I hope this is enough information so that this question can be its own independent entity.

Comment: Generally, $\text{var}(cX) = c^2\text{var}(X)$. if X and Y are independent, $\text{var}(X + Y) = \text{var}(X) + \text{var}(Y)$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables

Comment: @MichaelHoppe How does one use the formula Var $\sum^{n}_{i=1}X_{i} = \sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{n}_{i=1}Cov(X_{i},X_{j})$ .I am not to sure how one applies the Sum of correlated variables.

Comment: Although From Rodrigo's edit I am starting to see a correlation.

Comment: $\sigma^2_{aX+bY}=a^2\sigma^2_ X+b^2\sigma^2_Y+2ab\sigma_{XY}$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Where did you get the $a^2$ and $b^2$ it does not seem to be in the question?

Comment: In your case, for example $\sigma^2_{3X+5Z}=3^2\sigma^2_X+5^2\sigma^2_Z+2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\sigma_{XY}=9\cdot3+25\cdot8+30\cdot (-2)$.

Comment: The result would be $167$ I assume there must be more to this problem.

Comment: Why did you delete the values of the covariances that were in the question? This invalidates the published answer and makes the question impossible to answer.

Comment: Oh, and maybe **three** duplicates on the same problem are enough, don't you think?

Comment: @Did We'll see if anyone can answer it, but if it is impossible as you say it is then I will gladly give Rodrigas his best answer. I am looking for the knowledge and theory behind this, not just the answer.

Comment: There is no mystery here, the covariances are (obviously) needed, so if you want to wait for nothing, please do. The bounty is also slightly ridiculous, if you ask me. But, more to the point: **Why did you erase the values of the covariances from the question?**

Comment: @Did The reason is because I want to ask a distinct question. If I had not what makes this different than before? I need to clarify what needs attention and what does not. If you want to see what is was just check the edit history.

Comment: I had already checked the edit history, thanks. And yes, the present version of the question is absurd (but since you seem to have the utmost difficulties to actually read what the comments say, it is probably better for me to leave the matter).

Comment: Sorry Did, I think I understand what you mean I was thinking about another problem if X,Y,Z are independent then $cov(X,Y),cov(X,Z),Cov(Y,Z) = 0 $ I will edit this as this is what you were referring to probably. I guess the only questions I do have is how to understand the theorems without using linear algebra.

Comment: "Please explain how one gets cov(X,Y)....... and how one can use the appropriate formulas to get the right result based on the theorems I have provided." Wow, you are really not listening at all to what people explain to you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$Y := c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2 + c_3 X_3 = \mathrm c^\top \mathrm X$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb E (Y) = \mathrm c^\top \mathbb E (\mathrm X)$$

and

$$\mbox{Var} (Y) = \mathrm c^\top \left( \mathbb E (\mathrm X\mathrm X^\top) - \mathbb E (\mathrm X) \mathbb E (\mathrm X^\top) \right) \mathrm c = \mathrm c^\top \mbox{cov} (\mathrm X) \, \mathrm c$$

Using the data in the question,

$$\mbox{Var} (Y) = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ 4\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & -2\\ 1 & 2 & 3\\ -2 & 3 & 8\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ 4\end{bmatrix} = \cdots = 71$$

Comment: Is one suppose to multiply matrices in order to get 71. 
$$\mbox{Var} (Y) = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ 4\end{bmatrix}^\top\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & -2\\ 1 & 2 & 3\\ -2 & 3 & 8\end{bmatrix} \cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ 4\end{bmatrix} = \cdots = 71$$

Comment: I just wish I could wish away these thoughts but, how does one get 71 I just do not see it?

Comment: @LittleJon Using [SymPy Live](http://live.sympy.org), `M = Matrix([[3, 1, -2], [1, 2, 3], [-2, 3, 8]]); v = Matrix([1, -2, 4]); print v.T * M * v` produces `Matrix([[71]])`.

Comment: Sometimes I wish I had bought Matlab. Gracias Rodrigo.

Comment: I just wish I understood how you got all these values then I would be able to understand correctly what to do. It is just not clicking yet I almost got it.$$\mbox{Var} (Y) = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ 4\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & -2\\ 1 & 2 & 3\\ -2 & 3 & 8\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ 4\end{bmatrix} = \cdots = 71$$

Comment: @LittleJon Note that the main diagonal of the matrix contains the variances, whereas the off-diagonal entries contain the covariances. The row and column vectors contain the coefficients of the linear combination of the random variables. Note also that the expected values of the random variables are not used at all.

Comment: How can you multiply the matrices the inner dimensions are not the same? The product is undefined.

Comment: Also I still do not understand what you mean by diagonal? The variances are >$$\sigma_{x}^{2}=3 \qquad \qquad \sigma_{y}^{2}=2 \qquad \qquad \sigma^{2}_{z}=8$$
. Which diagonals do you mean? I am sorry man I still do not know how you got V.t, M and V and  how you derived the answer.

Comment: @LittleJon The dimensions are compatible. Note that the main diagonal of the matrix is indeed $3, 2, 8$. Deriving is easy if you're familiar with linear algebra.

Comment: Okay so you have $(3x1)(3x3)$, how does one multiply this? The inner dimensions are different. I get the main diagonal but the rest is confusing to me.

Comment: @LittleJon That vector is *transposed*.

Comment: $$ \mbox{Var} (Y) =\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1, -2, 4\end{bmatrix}  \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & -2\\ 1 & 2 & 3\\ -2 & 3 & 8\end{bmatrix} \right) \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ 4\end{bmatrix} = \cdots = 71$$ So then thats how you multipy make sense. But the hard part is still deriving the matrices which is very difficult to understand.

Comment: @LittleJon Note that matrix multiplication is *associative*.

Comment: So you get $(1x3)(3x3)=(1x3) \Rightarrow (1x3)(3x1)= 1x1 $

Comment: Which makes sense you get 71. I think we are getting close once I figured out how you got whats **inside** the matrices then I can get closure.

Comment: @LittleJon Just use the definition of the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X^{T}=(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})$, $a^{T}=(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})$, $b^{T}=(b_{1},b_{2},b_{3})$, $U=a^{T}X$ and $V=b^{T}X$.

Then, by definition,
\begin{equation*}
E(a^{T}X) = a^{T}E(X)=a^{T}\mu,\qquad Var(a^{T}X) = a^{T}Var(X)a = a^{T}\Sigma a
\end{equation*}
where $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are mean vector and variance-covariance matrix of $X$. With reference to the current example, $\mu = (2\;\; -3\;\; 4)^{T}$ and 
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3&1&-2\\
1&2&3\\
-2&3&8
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
Cov(U,V)&=&E\left((U-E(U))(V-E(V))\right)\\
&=&E\left[(a^{T}X-E(a^{T}X))(b^{T}X-E(b^{T}X))\right]\\
&=&E\left[(a^{T}X-(a^{T}\mu))(b^{T}X-(b^{T}\mu))\right]\\
&=&E\left[a^{T}(X-\mu)b^{T}(X-\mu) \right]\\
&=&E\left[a^{T}(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^{T}b \right]\\
&=&a^{T}E\left[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^{T}\right]b\\
&=&a^{T}\Sigma b
\end{eqnarray*}
Plug-in the expressions to get the required covariance.