# How to find The covariance of $U$ and $V= 3X-Y-Z.$?

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, variance

If the random variables $X,Y$ and $Z$ have the means $\mu_{x}=2,\mu_{y}=-3 \text{ and } \mu_{z} = 4$ the variances $\sigma_{x}^{2}=3,\sigma_{Y}^{2}=2 \text{ and } 
\sigma^{2}_{z}=8 \text{ and } \\\text{cov}(X,Y) =1,\text{cov}(X,Z) = -2 \text{ and } \text{Cov}(Y,Z) = 3, \text{ find }$

> The covariance of $U$ and $V= 3X-Y-Z.$

$U =71$

How does one get the answer$-54?$

I know that one is suppose to use the formula $\sigma_{xy}= \mu^{'}_{1,1}-\mu_{x}\mu_{Y}$

I know one needs to multiply in a certain way in order to derive the answer. However the process of deriving the exact formula eludes my comprehensions. Any tips on deriving the formula would be beneficial.

Comment: What is U? I think there is something missing

Comment: Are you also given $\Bbb{E}U$ and the covariances $\text{cov}(U,X_i)$ for $i=1,2,3$ where $X_i\in\{X,Y,Z\}$, but forgot to include them?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974771/how-to-find-the-variance-of-u-x-2y4z This is a two part question so I made them two questions as a result.

Comment: @LittleJon Does the answer help ?

Comment: It does help but I am still at the first part then I can move on to the second part of the question I just having trouble comprehending what Rodrigo did to get the answer for the first part.  
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974771/how-to-find-the-variance-of-u-x-2y4z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $cov(X-2Y+4Z,3X-Y-Z)$

Just multiply each summand of the first random variable by each summand of the second variable. The constants (numbers) can be factored out.

$=3cov(X,X)-cov(X,Y)-cov(X,Z)-6cov(X,Y)+2cov(Y,Y)-4cov(Y,Z)$

$+12cov(X,Z)-2cov(Y,Z)-4cov(Z,Z)$

Comment: The result is indeed $-54$.

Comment: What is cov(X,X), cov(Y,Y), and cov(Z,Z) equal to? This is not stated above?

Comment: @LittleJon That are the corresponding variances. $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)=\sigma_X^2=3$

Comment: So this is what we are doing $cov\left((X-2Y+4Z)\cdot(3X-Y-Z)\right)$
.

Comment: How did you get $-7cov(X,Y)$ Should that not be $-6cov(X,Y)$?

Comment: @Jon Yes, you´re right. Thanks for your comment. I always reply very quickly :)